# List notation and S-expressions in LISP

Tags: lisp

I was trying to learn the concept of `S-expressions` in `Lisp`. I came across with the following question:

> Give an example of an `S-expression` which cannot be
>   represented using the list notation.

What does `list notation` means? I understand the great idea of `sexps` but is it possible create a `sexp` which cannot be
represented using the list notation?  If so, what can I say about the binary tree which represents it?

Comment: It would be helpful to know where you came across this.  “List notation” is not a specific term in Lisp.  (Contrast “S-expression”, which has a very specific meaning.). @Svante gives some good responses, but to give a better answer, we’d need to know just what “list notation” means.

Answer (score 4):

In this context, I'd understand *list notation* to be the abbreviation of the *dotted pair notation* in the case of a linear chain: list notation `(a b c)` for the dotted pair notation `(a . (b . (c . nil)))`.

This would mean that anything that is not expressible as nested lists would fit the description: improper lists (i. e. the last `cdr` is not `nil`) or circular lists come to mind.

Improper list example: `(a b c . d)`.  The rightmost leaf is not `nil`.

Circular list: `#1=(a b c . #1#)`.  There is a cycle in the graph.